# How to return a value from a function that uses 'http.get()' method in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, get, return-value

I have a simple `HTTP GET` function that only needs to return the response in a function, but right now this function is returning `void`.

The code in `sitechecks.js`

```
var checkSite = () => {
    https.get('https://itmagazin.info', (res, err) => {
        if (res.statusCode === 200 && res.statusMessage === 'OK') {
            return `The site returned: ${res.statusMessage}`
        } else return `Error, the site returned: ${err.message}`
    })
}

module.exports = checkSite
```

And when I import the module in `index.js`, the `console` returns `[Function: checkSite]` and not the value itself.

```
// Index.js
var extSiteCheck = require('./sitechecks')

// This console prints [Function: checkSite] instead of "OK"
console.log(extSiteCheck.checkSite)
```

However, if I add the `return` statement on `http.get()` in the function, the `console` prints `undefined`. So I thought that this `undefined` is a progress, but I don't understand why does it return `undefined?`

(`return http.get()` in the **checkSite** function)

Any help, tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because callbacks in JavaScript are asynchronous, you can't return from within a callback.

That means this

`console.log(extSiteCheck.checkSite)`

runs before the request comes back.

You can try console logging within your callback (instead of trying to return a value), in order to see this in practice. But basically, whatever you are trying to achieve with the results of your `get` request, you need to do *inside* the callback.

Comment: Do you know any good documentation about callbacks? Links, videos?

Comment: A good general resource about JavaScript callbacks: http://callbackhell.com/;

And a great beginners' Node.js workshop: https://github.com/node-girls/node-workshop

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

mebbe something like ... console.log( extSiteCheck.checkSite()  );